# Evaluate a script (e.g. Python) in Java for Android platform

Tags: java, python, android, scripting

Is it possible to evaluate a string of python code (or Perl) from Java when developing Android applications?

I am trying to do something like evaluating a text-input script:

```
String script = text1.getText().toString();
String result = PythonRuntime.evaluate(script);
text2.setText(result);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you weren't aware of it, the [Android Scripting Environment](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) might be useful to you, though I don't think it does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

[Jython](http://www.jython.org/) and its derivatives should be able to do this. See also [Jythondroid](http://code.google.com/p/jythonroid/).